# Why are some of my link titles are being placed outside of my <a> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

[Here is a jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ofIvIlu/1/edit?html,js,console,output) so you can see what I mean.

As you can see some of my link titles are being placed outside the  tags. Initially I thought this was to do with the fact some of the titles were surrounded by double quotes. I build a function to replace these but it had no effect.

After logging the `title[i]` before it is appended into the DOM, I can't see any reason why some would be placed inside the  tags and some outside. If any one has any suggestions I would be very interested to hear them.

Comment: when using external hosting services you should [always, also, include the code in your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code)

Comment: my apologies,I will do so next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in `postURLs` function, change the line:

```
$("#" + subreddit + " > ul").append("<li><a href=" + url[i] + ">" + title[i] + "</a></li>");
```

to:

```
$("#" + subreddit + " > ul").append("<li><a href='" + url[i] + "'>" + title[i] + "</a></li>");
```

(just added single quotes to `href` attribute)

that will solve your problem.

next time, [please include the code in the question body as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code).

cheers.